# The VPN client agent was unable to create the interprocess communication depot

Tags: vpn, cisco-vpn-client

While installing Cisco AnyConnect 3.1.05170, the following error message appears in a dialog box.

```
Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client

The VPN client agent was unable to create the interprocess communication depot
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To resolve this issue on Windows 7:

1. Click the Windows `Start` button.
2. Click on `Control Panel`.
3. Set `View by:` to `Category`.
4. Click on `View network status and tasks` under `Network and Internet`.
5. Click on `Change adapter settings`.
6. Look for `Shared` in the `Status` column in the `Network Connections` window and right-click that device (e.g. Ethernet adapter, WiFi adapter) and click `Properties`.
7. Click the `Sharing` tab.
8. Clear the `Allow other network users to connect through this computer’s Internet connection` check box.
9. Click `OK`.
10. Reinstall Cisco AnyConnect.

These instructions may not be accurate for other versions of Windows besides 7.

Comment: WOW! This was the weirdest reason & this solution actually worked! Thanks. I was struggling for a long time around it.. :-)

Comment: I don't understand what I'm supposed to do in step 6, where's the status column and what connection should this be? Network sharing is currently enabled on my Wi-Fi adapter, and there is no real ethernet adapter (MacBook Air running Windows 8.1).

Comment: Yeah thanks, I just had to change the sharing settings for the active adapter (which was the physical Wi-Fi adapter in my case). Fixed the issue!

Comment: Check all your adapters, even the disconnected and disabled ones. I have an OpenVPN connection that I'm legitimately sharing (due to a Windows-only HSM) that prevented me from installing AnyConnect.

Answer (score 39):

Here are the steps to resolve the problem:

1. Press `Win` + `R`
2. Type: `services.msc` and press `Enter`
3. Find `Internet Connection Sharing (ICS)`
4. Stop the service
5. Right-click and open the service's `Properties`
6. Change the `Startup type:` to `Disabled`
7. Reboot the computer
8. Install Cisco AnyConnect VPN

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 10. I think it should be the accepted answer for that operating system.

Comment: What if the ICS is already deactivated?

Comment: what if this error is on ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

For MacOS users who still have this problem in 2023:

I successfully installed the client, but this error message pops up as a dialogue window every few minutes.

The following command line solved this problem:

```
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.cisco.anyconnect.vpnagentd.plist
```